# How to interpret the Thread Chart in ASMProfiler?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, profiling

I am starting to use [asmprofiler](https://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/) for some small programs I am doing as a hobby, now when I am watching the results I see a 'Thread Chart' tab and it shows each thread stack size and stack height vs (time?).

The problem is I don't understand what a thread's stack size and height mean and why this graph could be useful when profiling?

Answer (score 1):

As I read the source code for this program:

- Stack height is the number of function call stack frames present on the stack.
- Stack size if the size in bytes of the stack.

You might use these graphs if you were:

- debugging stack overflows, or
- trying to gain understanding of a recursive algorithms performance, or
- trying to optimise the reserved stack size for your threads, or
- many other reasons that I have not thought of!

Comment: you are totally right, to be honest I haven't used them myself (as creator of asmprofiler :) ) yet, but it was easy to implement, and hey: it *could* be useful :)